# Web Application Rename / Migrate with in the same SharePoint Farm?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, web-application

Current dilemma I face is that a client has a Web Application named http://site1 which is their production Web Application is a SP2013 Farm.

In this same Farm they started developing their new environment ( Call it http://site1dev ) which at Go Live is to become their production environment.

The catch is that at go live 'site1dev' needs to be renamed to respond to 'site1' and the existing 'site1' is to become 'site1old' till it's time of full decommissioning.

I have tried migrating the content DB's of the web application to a new one, this however fails as a result of the duplicate site collection ID's in the same farm even though the mount-spcontentdatabase is successful.

What would be the best way to achieve this? Can the IIS Sites be renamed / extended and then just have their bindings modified?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The more practical solution for this would be.

1. Create a new web application and a blank site collection
2. Take the backup of the older site collection and restore it in the new one .
3. Restore all the wsp's and config sections in the new web app.
4. configure all the AAM mappings.

This way, you dont need to face the content DB issues and also you dont need to manage the iis sites.

Alternatively, You may consider using the content deployment jobs after creating a blank web application.

Comment: Thank You. I started playing with doing it this way last night into a dummy site collection and seems to be working well so far. I expect I might bump into some issue's relating to my Apps later but for now this seems like it will do the trick.